# JS custom window object property is not visible when it is called

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

Project structure

```
src
 |- axios
 |     |- axios.js
 |- services
 |     |- service.js
 |- components
 |     |- App.js
 |- main.js (Vue instance)
```

---

**axios.js**

```
import axios from 'axios'

console.log('2. axios.js')
console.log(window) // show everything, with my custom prop abc
console.log(window.abc) // return undefined

const $http = axios.create({
    baseURL: '/api'
});
export default $http
```

**service.js**

```
const setWindowProps = () => {
    window.abc = 'abc'
}
export default setWindowProps
```

**index.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import setWindowProps from './services/service'

console.log('1. main.js')

setWindowProps()
Vue.use(Vuex);

new Vue({
    render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app');
```

console.log order:
- 2. - axios.js 
- window properties
- undefined
- 1. main.js

The problem is that the axios.js file is executed before the *setWindowProps()* function even though its first use is in the *APP.js* component.
Strangely, in *console.log(window)* in axios.js my abc key is visible correctly, but when I choose *console.log(window.abc)* returns *undefined* already.
Does anyone know what is the reason for this? Why is there a window in the object but you can't use it?

Comment: where do you import 'axios' in the main.js?

Comment: @mohammad in App.js and other components that are deeper and to several other services that are on the same level as services.js. I also use something like that in one service:
const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;